# What does it mean for an isogeny to be of "smooth degree?"

Tags: elliptic-curves, isogeny

I keep seeing references to isogenies of smooth degrees, but I can't seem to find a definition. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't know much about such things - but I think cryptographers refer to $N$ as smooth if it has lots of small prime factors, so perhaps the authors are saying that the degree of the isogeny is smooth in this sense?

Comment: Could you link the articles that you have seen the smooth degree? It is highly probable that is what Mummytheturkey said.